# The lock-screen of the Ubuntu BQ

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lock-screen, phone

What are colored circles stand for? The large dark one tells the date or rather the number of days that have passed in a month but I can't figure out the colored circles since they vary in size, color and location. Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colored circles on the outer ring are simply representative of how much activity you performed of the currently displayed metric, for the current and past days. If you double-tap the center of the large circle, it will switch to a different metric type (calls made, calls received, messages sent, messages received, etc…) and the outer circles will also change to match the new metric being displayed.